# Uninitialized variable error, compiles in Linux, doesn't compile in Visual Studio

Tags: c++

Here is a program I wrote for a C++ class I'm taking. I was able to compile it on my school's Linux server, but when I try to compile it on Microsoft Visual Studio, I get an error saying how the variables inside the parentheses of my functions in main are 'uninitialized'. [image: snapshot of the problem area in my code]

Any ideas on how to fix it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

double getIncome(double income);
double getBudgetedLiving(double budgetedLivingExpenses);
double getActualLiving(double actualLivingExpenses);
double getActualTax(double actualTaxesWithheld);
double getActualTithing(double actualTitheOfferings);
double getActualOther(double actualOtherExpenses);
double display(double income, double budgetedLivingExpenses,
    double actualLivingExpenses, double actualTaxesWithheld,
    double actualTitheOfferings, double actualOtherExpenses);
/************************************************************************
 *     MAIN organizes all of the functions in the correct order.
 *     starting with the 6 category-specific functions, and then
 *     lastly the display function which recalls the values and
 *     projects them onto a table.
 **********************************************************************/

int main()
{

    cout << "This program keeps track of your monthly budget\n"
        << "Please enter the following:" << endl;
    double income = getIncome(income);
    double budgetedLivingExpenses = getBudgetedLiving(budgetedLivingExpenses);
    double actualLivingExpenses = getActualLiving(actualLivingExpenses);
    double actualTaxesWithheld = getActualTax(actualTaxesWithheld);
    double actualTitheOfferings = getActualTithing(actualTitheOfferings);
    double actualOtherExpenses = getActualOther(actualOtherExpenses);

    display(income, budgetedLivingExpenses, actualLivingExpenses,
        actualTaxesWithheld, actualTitheOfferings, actualOtherExpenses);
    return 0;
}

double display(double income, double budgetedLivingExpenses,
    double actualLivingExpenses, double actualTaxesWithheld,
    double actualTitheOfferings, double actualOtherExpenses)
{
    cout.setf(ios::fixed);
    cout.setf(ios::showpoint);
    cout.precision(2);

    double budgetedTaxesWithheld = 0.0;
    double budgetedTitheOfferings = (income * .10);
    double budgetedOtherExpenses = (income - budgetedTaxesWithheld -
        budgetedTitheOfferings -
        budgetedLivingExpenses);
    double actualDifference = (income - actualTaxesWithheld -
        actualTitheOfferings -
        actualLivingExpenses -
        actualOtherExpenses);
    double budgetedDifference = 0.0;

    cout << endl;
    cout << "The following is a report on your monthly expenses\n"
        << "\tItem" << setw(24) << "Budget" << setw(17) << "Actual\n";
    cout << "\t=============== =============== ===============\n";
    cout << "\tIncome" << setw(11) << "$" << setw(11)
        << income << "    $" << setw(11) << income << endl;
    cout << "\tTaxes           " << "$" << setw(11)
        << budgetedTaxesWithheld << "    $" << setw(11)
        << actualTaxesWithheld << endl;
    cout << "\tTithing         " << "$" << setw(11)
        << budgetedTitheOfferings << "    $" << setw(11)
        << actualTitheOfferings << endl;
    cout << "\tLiving          " << "$" << setw(11)
        << budgetedLivingExpenses << "    $" << setw(11)
        << actualLivingExpenses << endl;
    cout << "\tOther           " << "$" << setw(11)
        << budgetedOtherExpenses << "    $" << setw(11)
        << actualOtherExpenses << endl;
    cout << "\t=============== =============== ===============\n";
    cout << "\tDifference      " << "$" << setw(11)
        << budgetedDifference
        << "    $" << setw(11) << actualDifference << endl;
    return 0;
}
/****************************************************************
 *     The 6 category functions take inputs such as income,
 *     budgeted living expenses, etc. from the user and sends them
 *     to display function.
 ***************************************************************/
double getIncome(double income)
{
    cout << "\tYour monthly income: ";
    cin >> income;
    return income;
}
double getBudgetedLiving(double budgetedLivingExpenses)
{
    cout << "\tYour budgeted living expenses: ";
    cin >> budgetedLivingExpenses;
    return budgetedLivingExpenses;
}
double getActualLiving(double actualLivingExpenses)
{
    cout << "\tYour actual living expenses: ";
    cin >> actualLivingExpenses;
    return actualLivingExpenses;
}
double getActualTax(double actualTaxesWithheld)
{
    cout << "\tYour actual taxes withheld: ";
    cin >> actualTaxesWithheld;
    return actualTaxesWithheld;
}
double getActualTithing(double actualTitheOfferings)
{
   cout << "\tYour actual tithe offerings: ";
   cin >> actualTitheOfferings;
   return actualTitheOfferings;
}
double getActualOther(double actualOtherExpenses)
{
   cout << "\tYour actual other expenses: ";
   cin >> actualOtherExpenses;
   return actualOtherExpenses;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have a declaration that both declares and references a variable (like `double budgetedLivingExpenses = getBudgetedLiving(budgetedLivingExpenses);`, the variable being passed to the function is uninitialized.  MSVC can display a warning for this, as it usually indicates a problem.  (Compilers are not required to issue a diagnostic when an uninitialized variable is used.  You do get Undefined Behavior when you do it.)

In your case, since you assign a new value to the parameter in your `get` functions before you read from it, you overwrite this passed-in uninitialized value.  So you don't need the parameter at all.  Just declare a local variable to hold the value within the function and return it like you already are.